# Produce Column of Calculated Values in List, nested in Tablix - SSRS Report Builder 2014

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to convert some old Crystal Reports files over to SSRS, and the layout calls for a section of dynamic rows inside an otherwise static tablix (table object).

In other words, the result should look like this:

```
Static Row
Dynamic Row 1
Dynamic Row 2
Dynamic Row 3
Static Row
```

Normally I would just drop a List into one of my table cells and arrange the data to be repeated. But the values to be shown in this list are all being calculated at run time -- the author of the report I'm trying to convert got very creative. Unfortunately, he's not available to ask about this stuff.

Anyway, this means I keep getting the error "The tablix has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members." I know this means "no calculations in lists", but I'm out of alternatives. I can't split my report into separate tables, because the whole tablix equals one set of report output. I've tried adding additional groups to my tablix, but that doesn't group my dynamic output together. Instead each row of the dynamic row set gets treated as a separate report element, meaning I get multiple reports when I should only get one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what the data is exactly or what details is producing, but could a subreport be used?

Comment: As @JerryRitcey states, sub reports may be the answer but it's hard to tell unless we see the report design and data. Subreports can be placed inside your tablix cell.

Comment: I've run into this before, I think I solved it by using a matrix instead.